# Blur part of the image using user input [Flutter]

Tags: flutter

So I have an image that needs to be blurt but only at the location the user drags his finger.

I have an image that is drawn using:

```
final UI.Rect rect = UI.Offset.zero & size;
final Size imageSize =
    Size(_image.width.toDouble(), _image.height.toDouble());
FittedSizes sizes = applyBoxFit(BoxFit.contain, imageSize, size);
final Rect inputSubrect =
    Alignment.center.inscribe(sizes.source, Offset.zero & imageSize);
final Rect outputSubrect =
    Alignment.center.inscribe(sizes.destination, rect);

canvas.drawImageRect(_image, inputSubrect, outputSubrect, Paint());
```

And the blur effect using:

```
canvas.drawRect(Rect.fromPoints(_blurStart, _points[i + 1].offset),
            blurPaintSettings);
```

where _blurStart is the first point of contact and _points[i+1] is the last.

The blur paint is this:

```
  Paint blurPaintSettings = new Paint()
..style = PaintingStyle.fill
..maskFilter = MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.normal, 3.0);
```

But at the moment all I get it this:
[Black spots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEhAH.png)

I already tried using:

```
 canvas.saveLayer(Rect.fromPoints(_blurStart, _points[i + 1].offset),
        blurPaintSettings)
```

but that doesn't show anything

Comment: Try specifying the `color` of Paint as `Colors.transparent`

Comment: That just makes the entire box transparent so it doesn't show anything

Comment: You are bluring rectangle, which you draw on canvas, not the image. But you can try Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5) in your code - maybe it will look like blur